# Config security for a Hard Disk Drive

Tags: windows-7

I configured nobody can access my hard disk drive except me. So what happen if I reinstall my Windows 7? Can I still access to hard disk drive?

Comment: how did you do the security?

Comment: right click to the hard disk drive -> Security tab -> remove all account in "Group or user names" list except my account.

Comment: @linhtm - I guarantee I could enable the built-in Administrator account on your computer if given 20 minutes alone with it.  If you encrypt your hdd you will make what I can do not possible.

Answer (score 2):

You would still be able to access your hard drive, however the new installation would require you to take ownership of any of the old directories not reinstalled by Windows.

FYI your method will only prevent people who *log in* to your current Windows from accessing the hard drives files.  This would not prevent access from booting to another OS, like a Linux LiveCD.  Nor would this prevent someone from accessing your files by removing the drive and connecting it to another system.